# MEF prevent class from being manually instatiated

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I wonder if I can somehow prevent class from being manually created? I want to make sure it is only imported.

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class TwoWayMessageHubService
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public TwoWayMessageHubService(ILoggerService loggerService)
    {
    }
}
```

So, I want to make sure this works:

```
[Import]
public TwoWayMessageHubService MHS {get; set;)
```

And make sure this doesn't:

```
var MHS = new TwoWayMessageHubService(logger);
```

Comment: Not really a solution, but what if you marked the constructor as `[Obsolete]` and made FxCop/StyleCop (not remember which) throw compilation error on usage of `Obsolete` fields/methods?

Comment: Why intentionally cripple your code though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact this is possible. Just have to apply **[Import]** attribute to your constructor's parameters and make your constructor private. I have made the following sample based on your code, it works and you can test it.

First, the **TwoMessageHubService** with the changes I mentioned:

```
[Export]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
    public class TwoWayMessageHubService
    {
        [ImportingConstructor]
        private TwoWayMessageHubService([Import]ILogger logger) { }
    }
```

Notice that the constructor is **private**

Then a class that must be composed with an instance of TwoWayMessageHubService:

```
public class Implementer
    {
        [Import]
        public TwoWayMessageHubService MHS { get; set; }
    }
```

The Logger decorated with **Export**

```
   public interface ILogger { }

    [Export(typeof(ILogger))]
    public class Logger : ILogger { }
```

And Main:

```
var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            var implementer = new Implementer();
            container.ComposeParts(implementer);
            //var IdoNotCompile = new TwoWayMessageHubService(new Logger());

            Console.ReadLine();
```

If you uncomment the comment (lol) then you will notice that it does not compile.

Hope this helps

Comment: Great! Just need to make sure default constructor not used, `private TwoWayMessageHubService()  {   }` and then it's all as it should be